# Why is my pi camera v2.1 detected but not taking pictures?

Tags: pi-3, hardware, camera, raspicam, raspbian-stretch

Thanks for your help. Yesterday I moved my Raspberry Pi cam v2.1 with the rpi robot chassis and the camera won’t take pictures. But, the day before, the camera functioned properly. Why do you think this is happening, is the camera damaged? I've tried pressing all the chips I could on the camera's circuit board in case a chip (like Sunny) was loose. And I've tried the camera with two different Raspberry Pis using the same micro SD card. Thanks for your help.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -v -o newpic.jpg

raspistill Camera App v1.3.11

Width 3280, Height 2464, quality 85, filename newpic.jpg
Time delay 5000, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
Camera component done
Encoder component done
Starting component connection stage
Connecting camera preview port to video render.
Connecting camera stills port to encoder input port
Opening output file newpic.jpg
Enabling encoder output port
Starting capture -1
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
^Cmmal: Aborting program

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354280/raspberry-camera-error-mmal-no-data-received-from-sensor#32225248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Fabian's comment and attached link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354280/raspberry-camera-error-mmal-no-data-received-from-sensor#32225248

Turns out the error message was correct:

```
mmal: No data received from sensor. 
Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

My problem was I put the camera in while the Pi was on. I bought another camera, which works.